# Determine the first node in a Linked List

Tags: c++, c, linked-list, nodes

If the last node of a linked list is connected to the first node, it makes a ring.
Then how would you identify which of the nodes in the linked list is the first node and the last one?

Comment: what's the start of a circle?

Comment: If the nodes form a ring, there is no first node and no last node. What do you mean ?

Comment: By the way, what you have is called a "Circular(ly) linked list".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wouldn't. If it is a ring, then first and last are meaningless. Any node can be first or last.

If you define "first" as "created first", then you would probably want to add some sequencing information to the nodes to be able to know that.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably there would be a pointer to the first node of a linked list (you need a way of entering the list). Additionally it is convenient in this case to maintain a pointer to the last node in the list.

If you are more specific about what you need to know I can be more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

What you are describing is a circularly linked list. It is possible to know both the first and last item in the list based off just maintaining the last node. Logically that requires it's successor to be the first node.

wikipedia has a bit more about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_list

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to implement a circular list, have a look here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Circularly_linked_list

Answer (score 1):

When you create the Linkedlist, store the address of the first node in a variable(preferably a private variable) so that at any point of time , you can compare this address with the current node's address